# SwiftUI How to push to next screen when tapping on Button

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I can navigate to next screen by using NavigationButton (push) or present with PresentationButton (present) but i want to push when i tap on Buttton()

```
Button(action: {
// move to next screen
}) {
   Text("See More")
}
```

is there a way to do it?

Comment: swiftUI you can use only 2 option using `NavigateButton (push) or present with PresentationButton`

Comment: then, is there a way to hide arrow when using NavigateButton, i just want to show "See More" text, tapping on it should push to next screen?

Answer (score 7):

**You can do using `NavigationLink`**

> **Note:** Please try in real device. in simulator sometimes not work properly.

```
struct MasterView: View {
    @State var selection: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Button("Press me") {
                        self.selection = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailsView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Button("Go Back") {
                self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see to display the new view, add the `NavigationLink` with `isActive: $pushView` using `<.hidden()>` to hide the navigation "arrow".

Next add `Text("See More")` with `tapGesture` to make the text respond to taps. The variable `pushView` will change (false => true) when you click "See More" text.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var pushView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            List {
                HStack{
                    Text("test")
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: NewView(), isActive: $pushView) {
                        Text("")
                    }.hidden()
                        .navigationBarTitle(self.pushView ? "New view" : "default view")
                    Text("See More")
                        .padding(.trailing)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.pushView.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("New View")
    }
}
```

[ContentView picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYyod.png)

[NewView picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYpmT.png)

Comment: Could you please explain what you did instead of just posting your code?

Comment: As you can see, to display new view add the "NavigationLink" with "isActive: $pushView" But using <.hidden()> not to show up the navigation "arrow". Then add Text("See More") with tapGesture to click like button. The variable "pushView" will change (false => true) when you click "See More" text.

Answer (score 1):

To tap on button and navigate to next screen,You can use NavigationLink like below

```
NavigationView{
       NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) {
             Text("Login")
              .padding(.all, 5)
              .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: 45, alignment: .center)
              .foregroundColor(Color.white)
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavigationLink` to implement this:

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello world")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Int? = nil
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailsView(), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Button("Press me") {
                        self.selection = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```